# Use custom Feature Icon for SPFx

Tags: spfx, feature, design, spfx-extensions

Is there a way to use a custom icon for SharePoint Framework features? When we navigate to the Site Settings, it would be nice to see our branded icon instead of the default one.

[image]

Part of the**package-solution.json**

I don't see any icon-related properties here:

```
"features": [
      {
        "title": "Application Extensions - Top Header & Footer",
        "description": "Deploys application extensions to display a Header at the Top placeholder and a Footer at the Bottom placeholder",
        "id": "24125f88-b8dd-46e1-acd4-a801e650709c",
        "version": "1.0.0.0",
        "assets": {
          "elementManifests": [
            "elements.xml"
          ]
        }          
      }
]
```

My best guess is that it's impossible, but can someone confirm it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I agree that it’s not possible or recommended . SPFx uses the Feature Framework (elements.xml) to handle features and it does not have a native api to set the image.

(There were workarounds available like this https://www.vrdmn.com/2011/09/change-feature-image-in-sandbox.html when using Sandbox solutions but they are no longer recommend)